# SQL Server 2008 - Select last 3 Booking Ids for each supplier

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank

Id like to return the top three most recent `BOOKING_ID`, by `CREATION_DATE` for each active `SUPPLIER_ID` within a column of bookings.

The active `SUPPLIER_ID` are gathered with the following query.

```
select SUPPLIER_ID 
into #active 
from BookingTable 
where BOOKING_ID in (select BOOKING_ID 
                     from BookingTable 
                     where CREATION_DATE > getdate() - 90) 
group by SUPPLIER_ID
```

Is it possible to do this as one query? My current approach is to enter the active `SUPPLIER_ID`'s into a temporary table, and using an outer join to somehow return three records for each supplier.

My expected output is:

```
SUPPLIER   BOOKING
1          12345
1          54656
1          34546
2          54965
2          05650
2          90565
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [ranking_functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)  by partitioning through supplier_id

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER( 
                    partition BY supplier 
                    ORDER BY creation_date DESC) AS rn 
         FROM   table) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn <= 3
```

Comment: Thanks very much, worked great, added FROM to my cte, then joined this table to improve my query.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it ??

```
select top 3 from table order by CREATION_DATE desc group by SUPPLIER_ID
```

or like other answer by @Vijaykumar Hadalgi using cte and ROW_NUMBER()/RANK() and PARTITION